# Open SSL get certificate from server

Tags: openssl

Which function in OpenSSL c library gets the certificate from the server, checks whether a valid certificate and returns according to the validity. Like valid, untrusted etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After establishing the connection just call `SSL_get_verify_result(ssl)` on your connection object `ssl`

```
if (SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK) {
       /* verification failed */
}
```

the possible return-codes for `SSl_get_verify_result()` can be found at [the man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html#) in the Diagnostics section

if you need to get the certificate and validate it yourself, you might want to look at
`SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl)` to get the certificate and `X509_verify_cert()`.